# Android Studio SDK error

Tags: android-studio

So i have downloaded and updated my android studio to the most recent version.

When i try to create a new project from the quick start window, it works fine until the minimum SDK and target SDK selection.

When i click to choose the SDK, the selection bar doesn't open.

Is it because i haven't installed any SDK's on my computer yet?

If that's the problem, how do i install SDK's to android studio?

My eclipse works fine but i wanna move on to more new stuff.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Android-Studio installation comes with the sdk so you must be having the sdk. What the problem might be that you may not be having platforms.

You can go to

`Tools>Android>SDK Manager`

in android-studio which opens the Android SDK Manager. It will show you a list of platforms and add-ons/tools you can download. But I can see that you can't get past the quick start window so this might not work until you open the main android-studio window.

Alternatively you can launch the SDK manager by manually opening the folder in which it is stored. It will be at

`your-android-studio-install-folder/sdk/tools/lib/SDK Manager.exe`

If you have eclipse working, then you must have previously downloaded the android-sdk before. Then you can find the `platforms` folder, in which you will find previously downloaded sdk platforms(Folders with names of platform versions like '10','18','15' etc.)

What you can do is copy/paste these folders into the `android-studio/sdk/platforms/` folder and android-studio will detect them automatically. This way you wont need to download those platforms again.